# DefinitelyTyped for graphql

Tags: typescript, graphql, definitelytyped

I am trying to get type definitions for graphql. I have installed both `graphql` and `@types/graphql` and in my file I have `import * as graphql from "graphql"`. However, I am unable to access types such as `GraphQLSchemaConfig`. How am I to access those? The type definitions seem to be loading correctly, as the constructor asks for an argument of that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GraphQLSchemaConfig` is defined and exported in the `type/schema.d.ts` file. The `index.d.ts` file, though, only re-exports `GraphQLSchema`. We can work around this by  doing...

```
 import { GraphQLSchemaConfig } from "graphql/type/schema";
```

There are details in the [definitely typed repository graphql directory.](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/graphql)

- `index.d.ts` contains `export * from './type';`
- `type/index.d.ts` contains `export { GraphQLSchema } from './schema';`
- `type/schema.d.ts` contains `export interface GraphQLSchemaConfig { /* ... */ )`

It's this last file that we need to reference in order to import `GraphQLSchemaConfig`.